# Android: Open an application on background, not a new task

Tags: java, android, appcelerator-titanium

I have this code inside a service:

```
PackageManager pm = app.getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.getPackageName());

intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

app.startActivity(intent);
```

And this opens the app on top of task stack. I would like to know if is possible to start the app on the low, on background. That if you press the task manager button on the phone it displays the app.
Is there a way?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: try by adding New Task flag in intent.

Comment: Hi @SohailZahid I already have the New Task flag on my Intent: line 5.

Comment: Hi @RahulRaina, the way my code works now, it opens the app on top of tasks, making it the active app, doesn't matter what app user is using. I don't like this, I prefer that if opens on the background, so users can switch to it later

Comment: oh sorry i haven't see .... is there any info in logs?

Comment: app is your servie context?

Comment: No problem @SohailZahid, there's no useful logs, I mean, because the code just works. It opens the app, but in the front of every other app. I would like it to open the app on the background

Answer (score 1):

No. But you could have the app send itself immediately to the background in the `onCreate()` of the first `Activity` like this:

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```